# Generic triviality of $G$-bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, galois-cohomology

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $X$ a curve over $k$. Then any $G$-bundle on a curve (where $G$ is reductive and connected) is generically trivial. This is the one of the main results of Borel and Springer's paper "rationality property of linear algebraic groups." In more detail: Tsen's theorem says that $k(X)$ has cohomological dimension $1$ which leaves checking that $H^1(k(X), G) = 1$. This is a calculation that holds for $G$ reductive and connected.

An analogue for this in topology is the following: suppose that I have a Riemann surface $X$, then puncturing $X$, I get a deformation retraction to a wedge of circles. Hence, on this punctured curve (which I think about as an open dense subset of $X$), a $G$-bundle is classified by a map $X \setminus x \rightarrow BG$. Therefore if $\pi_1(BG) = \pi_0(G) = 0$, then this $G$-bundle is trivial. In this situation, I might say that every topological $G$-bundle on a Riemann surface is "generically trivial" so that the above phenomenon might be seen as an algebro-geometric analogue of what happens in topology. This motivates my question:

I am asking for generalizations/analogues of this "generic triviality" statements; for example:

1. What if the moduli problem is changed, i.e. if instead of $G$-bundles I look at some other moduli problems (i.e. if I think of the above as saying that the map $X \rightarrow BG$ as generically trivial, are there examples of stacks $M$ such that $X \rightarrow M$ is generically trivial as well? What if $X$ is something special like $\mathbb{P}^1$?). At least in topology, it seems that the "homotopy groups" of the "moduli problem" might control generic triviality.
2. What happens if $X$ is a higher dimensional varieties? Like the comment by Jason Starr below, I am looking for any special cases of $G$ where this might hold.

Any reference/special cases would be appreciated!

Comment: Please give accurate attributions: Tsen's theorem is the assertion that $k(X)$ has cohomological dimension 1, whereas the vanishing of H$^1(K,G)$ for fields $K$ of cohomological dimension 1 and connected (!) reductive $K$-groups $G$ is much deeper (due to Steinberg for perfect $K$, and Borel--Springer in general). This has no reason to admit generalizations to a wider class of moduli problems (i.e., the reason it holds is tied up with the deep structure theory of reductive groups), so the 1st question seems to lack motivation. The 2nd question has many counterexamples for surfaces $X$.

Comment: "What happens if $X$ is a higher dimensional varieties?"  There is a generalization to $2$-dimensional varieties if $G$ is a simply connected, semisimple group.

Comment: Also, there cannot be a generalization to dimension $>1$ for arbitrary semisimple groups.  Serre's book on Galois cohomology is an excellent place to begin learning this subject.

Comment: Hi @grghxy. I apologize for the poor attributions, I hope it's corrected now. I also edited for more motivation - which is naive, but I hope to learn something even if it's about how naive it is!

Comment: Hi @JasonStarr thank you very much for your comments! Is the generalization to surfaces (for the $G$'s you mentioned) available in Serre's book (or at least something I can try and tackle myself by the techniques therein)?

Comment: @EldenElmanto.  "Is the generalization to surfaces ... available in Serre's book?"  The generalization to surfaces is as follows: de Jong, A. J.; He, Xuhua; Starr, Jason Michael *Families of rationally simply connected varieties over surfaces and torsors for semisimple groups.* Publ. Math. Inst. Hautes Études Sci. No. 114 (2011), 1–85.